# Need help create a generic function to check for value

Tags: php, variables

Anyone have any ideas on how to create a generic function to do this in a much shorter fashion?

```
if (($item['Quantity'] > 9) && ($item['Quantity'] < 20)) {  $bogo_item = 1; }
else if (($item['Quantity'] > 19) && ($item['Quantity'] < 30))  { $bogo_item = 2; } else if (($item['Quantity'] > 29) && ($item['Quantity'] < 40))  { $bogo_item = 3; } else if (($item['Quantity'] > 39) && ($item['Quantity'] < 50))  { $bogo_item = 4; }
...
```

And so forth...  Basically, I would like to create a function that will check and compare a variable $item['Quantity'] and see if it fits in one of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical lookup problem...

You could create an array of triples:
(I'm not a PHP programmer, but here's some JavaScript)

```
// position 0=lower limit, position 1=upper limit, position 2=bogo item value
var values = [ [9, 20, 1], [19, 30, 2], [29, 40, 3], [39, 50, 4] ];
```

Then you can write a generic loop:

```
for (var i= 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    if ((item.quantity > values[i][0] && (item.quantity < values[i][1]) {
        return values[i][2];
    }
}
```

HTH